# Have you used boost::tribool in real work?

Tags: c++, boost

tribool strikes me as one of the oddest corners of Boost.  I see how it has some conveniences compared to using an enum but an enum can also be easily expanded represent more than 3 states.

In what real world ways have you put tribool to use?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

While I haven't used C++, and hence boost, I have used three-state variables quite extensively in a network application where I need to store state as true/false/pending.

Comment: Yes, general async or polling situations seem to be a natural fit for tribool.

Comment: But did your application use the same logic as `boost::tribool`? I.e. `(bool)triValue` is `true` iff `triValue==true`; `triVal1==triVal2` is `indeterminate` iff any of the values is `indeterminate` etc.? Without the logic operations `tribool` looks useless as it's easy to substitute it with an enum.

Answer (score 17):

An extra state in any value type can be extremely valuable. It avoids the use of "magic numbers" or extra flags to determine if the value of a variable is "maybe" or "unknown".

Instead of `true` or `false`, the state of a `tribool` is `true`, `false`, or `indeterminate`.

Let's say you have a database that contains a list of `customers` and their `dateOfBirth`. So you write a function along the lines of :

```
tribool IsCustomerAdult(customerName);
```

The function returns:

> ```
> `true` if the customer is 18 or older;
> `false` if the customer is less than 18;
> `indeterminate` if the customer is not in the database 
>      (or the dateOfBirth value is not present).
> ```

Very useful.

Comment: I'd throw an exception if the customer wasn't found, but I can see how tri-state is useful in the latter.

Comment: for this scenario, `boost::optional` is an option too.

Comment: Wow, had not noticed it... `optional<bool>` and `tribool` more or less map the same concept ("false, true, or something else entirely") though their semantics are quite different. And now I'm wondering what a `optional<tribool>` be used for...

Comment: @GManNickG if you are throwing exceptions for those kinds of things then you are abusing exceptions.

Comment: @DanielW: Not really. I don't think my comment holds in general, but if you have a container that you expect to contain all your customers birthdays (and you want to be able to guarantee it because it's an invariant of the container), then returning something that is explicitly impossible due to the guarantees you provide is pointless.

Comment: @GManNickG if you don't think your comment holds in general then fine. I'm just worried about new developers who use exceptions as a quick hack to not have to think about the possible states. I'm a big proponent of carefully selected types that shows the intent of the function, in this case tribool seems perfect. Too many times have I heard developers say: "Ahh but that is an edge case! Don't you worry about it". It never ends well.

Comment: @DanielW: Agreed. Frankly, I don't even know why I added that comment originally in the first place, it seems out of place. But it was 5 years ago... (holy crap, it's been 5 years?!)

Comment: @Luis Machuca. optional<tribool> could be useful (in the database example) to differentiate "No record found" (optional-empty) and "Record found but no dateOfBirth" (optional-exists but tribool value is indeterminate)

Comment: Even if I can agree that you can give meaning to an optional<tribool>, I think it makes things very hard to understand and get right. If you really need to have four states (record not found, record found but no age information, adult, not adult) then I would recommend an enum.

Comment: You should use tribool under generic contexts.  In this example, make an enumerated value.  Something like: `OF_AGE, NOT_OF_AGE, UNKNOWN`

Answer (score 12):

I think the extra benefit is not only the 3rd value, but also that you can easily use the 3-valued logic!

For example:

```
(true && indeterminate) == indeterminate
(true || indeterminate) == true
```

SQL implements such logic.

Comment: Wow, I'd simply asssumed any comparison involving `null` decayed to `null`, but on researching this (for SQL), you're right: `null OR true == true`. Mind blown.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen numerous examples of two booleans being used to represent three possible states, explicitly or otherwise, with the fourth state being silently assumed to be impossible.  In at least two cases, I've changed such constructions to use tribool since we started using boost.

Comment: Me too though the use of bools might have been inappropriate to begin with and since the app was mature I was confident that conditions (specs, etc) were not going to change to 4 or 5 states.  Good use case.

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of the Boost library and started using it at company who I have since left.  After getting exposure to and using the boost library extensively throughout our project I stumbled on tribool and was considering using for some "Fuzzy Logic" algorithms needing improvements.

I left before I had a chance to get into it, but beyond the "Fuzzy Logic" example, other modules in the system had components with this sort of between state that considering now, I would probably end up using tribool in a decent amount of code if I was still with the company.

-bn

Answer (score 1):

I think it is very useful for Language moulding such as OCR applications and Speech synthesis because as you know human languages are ambiguous and they have a lot of Intermediate statuses

looking foreword to improve the current technologies using the tribool